# ExtJs doesnt recognize changes on my store

Tags: extjs, store, record

my ExtJS doesnt recognize any changes i made on the record of the store.

Here is the code:

```
        handler: function () {
            var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('anfrage-store');
            var rec = store.getAt(0);
            rec.data.rgKeinKauf = 1;
            store.save();
        }
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call a method so the record/store can react to the change. All you're doing there is setting some arbitrary property on an object.

```
rec.set('rgKeinKauf', 1);
```